# What's the most maintainable way to get html tags from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, tags

I need to get a html tag from string and append in a html. Actually I have this code to handle this requirement.

```
var str = '<div id="option0" class="course-quiz-option"><input class="course-quiz-input" type="radio" name="answer[7][]" id="gensym_21" value="21">Option 1. </div>,0,21'; 
var lastTag =  str.lastIndexOf(">");
var tag = str.substr(0,lastTag+1);

$("#main").append(tag);
```

[This is the complete code in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tabares/5MDsn/7/)

Comment: What's your question?  You seem to have a working solution.

Comment: I get and want this "<div id="option0" class="course-quiz-option"><input class="course-quiz-input" type="radio" name="answer[7][]" id="gensym_21" value="21">Option 1. </div>", but I want a best way to obtain this result, Actually I have the code above like a solution.

Comment: Best as in fastest?  Most maintainable? Coolest?  I favor regex for doing any sort of string pattern matching.  But what you've done above, if the format is consistent in all future use cases, works just fine.  "best" is subjective to your aims.

Comment: _"What's the most maintainable way to get html tags from string?"_ - That really depends on the format of the string. The "best" answer for the string shown in the question may not work at all for some other string... (And in my opinion taking steps to avoid having a JavaScript variable containing input like that would be better - can't you generate the string without the ",0,21" part on the end?)

Comment: For maintainability, I would assume that the future condition of the strings containing html is not always going to be the same format and take a look at implementing regex to find and extract html from strings.  It's not a subject for the faint of heart, but very powerful and easy to maintain because it doesn't rely on string character positions but rather the pattern of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#main").append($(str).get(0));
```